# Iterate through a tuple of numbers alternating between positive and negative values of the number

Tags: python, iteration

I want to iterate through numbers to give the output:

```
(0,0)
(1,0)
(0,1)
(0,-1)
(-1,0)
(1,-1)
(-1,1)
(1,1)
(2,0)
(-2,0)
(2,1)
(-2,1)
(2,-1)
(2,2)
(0,2)  # the order in which they come isn't important as long as it doesn't start the next absolute value once all smaller have been done i.e. don't start two once every combination of 0,1 and -1 has been found
...
# up to n, unless the condition is met then it will break the loop
```

So effectively every combination of positive and negative numbers up to `+/- n`.

I'm currently using this `for a, b in itertools.permutations(range(-n,n), 2):`. However, I'm then appending all the values to an array (`valid_answers`) and finding the smallest sum of absolute values of them. (`vals = sorted(valid_answers, key=lambda t: sum([abs(t[0]), abs(t[1])]))`)

I just want to iterate from 0 rather than from `-n` to `n`. It will break the first time the condition is met. I hope this code is sufficient to explain what I want to do. If not the full code (well enough to replicate what I am doing) is available [here](https://pastebin.com/CebsZu5W). (*lines 51 onwards*)

**Edit**
I am thinking maybe multiplying by powers of -1 is a possible approach to take but I am not too how to approach it.

Comment: Sorting to find a minimum value is inefficient, as you spend time ordering pairs whose relative order you don't care about. Use the `heapq` module instead. But that seems like a moot point; the smallest sum of absolute values is always going to be 0+0.

Comment: I only need values that meet a certain condition, the ones appended to the set. @chepner

Comment: You never mentioned anything about only selecting a subset of the pairs.

Comment: It is mentioned at the end of the code block, I have also added it to the answer.

Comment: I also don't see the problem iterating over `range(-n, n+1)` as opposed to iterating over `range(0, n+1)` and creating multiple pairs per value. You're just shifting the work.

Comment: Iterating from `range(-n, n+1)` will take a lot longer if there's an answer at `(0,1)`, for example. Especially as n get's large.

Comment: No, I only want a 2-tuple of the permutations up to n, not an n-tuple.

Comment: Unsure as to why this question has been closed due to being similar to the other question. Agreed it is similar but I’d say it sufficiently different.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little verbose but it should work.

```py
from itertools import permutations


def get_values(n):
    out = []
    if n < 0:
        return out

    out.append((0, 0))
    if n == 0:
        return out

    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        out += [(i, j) for j in range(-i, i + 1)]
        out += [(-i, j) for j in range(-i, i + 1)]
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I went for.

```
def get_values(n: int) -> list:
    if n < 0:
        return []

    if n == 0:
        return [(0, 0)]

    out = set()
    for i in range(0, n + 1):
        for j in range(0, i + 1):
            out.add((i, j))
            out.add((-i, j))
            out.add((i, -j))
            out.add((-i, -j))
    return sorted(out, key=lambda t: abs(t[0]))


...



for item in get_values(n=1000):
    a, b = item
    ...
```

It creates a set (no duplicates) and adds all combinations of the numbers to the set. Then returns a sorted list of this set. I don't think it's the most efficient way of doing it so would appreciate faster, cleaner etc. methods.

This answer was largely taken from another answer so thanks!

Comment: This is a very memory intensive solution so I think it's far from ideal!